# Error when trying to pip a package in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, sqlite, pip

I am trying to pip [sqlitebck](https://pypi.org/project/sqlitebck/) on Windows 10 but I keep getting this annoying error:

```
C:\Users\hdesk>pip install sqlitebck
Collecting sqlitebck
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/78/4eea86c275cf13aab545514833728cca99cfe330f4faa5645eafefdf9a1b/sqlitebck-1.4.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: sqlitebck
  Running setup.py install for sqlitebck ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\hdesk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\hdesk\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gwpozgjo\\sqlitebck\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\hdesk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-10ai8099\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'sqlitebck' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -I/usr/local/include -Ic:\users\hdesk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ic:\users\hdesk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /Tcsrc/sqlitebck.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/sqlitebck.obj
    sqlitebck.c
    c:\users\hdesk\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-gwpozgjo\sqlitebck\src\_sqlite/connection.h(33): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I spent a long time trying to fix it but I couldn't. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: This package needs the actual sqlite (sqlite itself, *not* the (built-in) Python package) development files. You'll need to a development version of sqlite on your system. (Unfortunately, this is not mentioned in the README file of sqlitebck.)

Comment: @9769953 Thank you so much. How can I install the actual sqlite? I tried `pip install pysqlite3` but it seems it is not the solution

Comment: No, you need the actual sqlite library, *with* its development files (which is few .c and .h files). Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Windows. You may have to search for "Windows install sqlite development files" or similar.